# Constraints doesn't work for Ipad xamarin.forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am working with xamarin.forms and using constraints to center and scale a logo in my splash screen. The problem is: The constraint that I define to Iphone  5s, 6, 6s etc.. doesn't work to the Ipad, and when I define it to the Ipad, it doesn't work to Iphones...
Does someone know how to solve that?

Iphones contraint (in right positions etc):

[image]

Ipads constraint (it's is wrong here):

[image]

Comment: What is the constraints that you have define for your Logo?

Comment: Share the constraints on the logo  and did you click the update frame button  after you change the device?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to center the logo in the screen, I am not sure why you would go with different Size classes for iPhone and Tablet.

- Instead of W-Compact, H-Regular for iPhone and W-Regular, H-Regular
  for iPad, I would suggest you to apply your constraint with W-Any,
  H-Any & View As should be : Generic. [image: Screenshot]
- If you set W-Compact, H-Regular, the constraint applies to
  iPhone(Portrait) device.
- If you set W-Regular, H-Regular, the constraint applies to iPad
  devices(Both Orientation).
- If you set W-Any, H-Any, the constraint will be applied regardless of
  the device size and orientation.

To Center the logo, I would recommend 4 constraint to be set for the Logo.

1. Width = Fix Width
2. Height = Fix Height
3. CenterX to Parent = 0
4. CenterY to Parent = 0

-----or-----

1. Top Space to Parent = 0
2. Bottom Space to Parent = 0
3. Leading Space to Parent = 0
4. Trailing Space to Parent = 0

Set, UIImageView mode to Aspect Fit.

Hope it helps.